# counting the number of columns of a csv file

Tags: linux, csv, unix, multiple-columns

I am currently working on something in which I need to be able to count the amount of columns (fields) in a csv file.

I've tried several things in the Linux shell and thought this should work:

```
head -1 police.csv | sed 's/[,]//g'| wc -c
```

This returns an illegal byte sequence. The name of the file is police.

Is there anyone that can help? I also think I need to use the , as a delimiter.

Comment: Use `tr` to replace the `,` with a new line. Then, count new lines with `wc -l`. You can probably do it directly with other tools like Awk.

Answer (score 1):

```
head -1 test.csv | sed 's/[^,]//g' | wc -c
```

Please use this command. It is working fine and giving the correct results.

Comment: this is my csv file test.csv . you can use police.csv instead

Comment: sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence This is the error that I em getting after I've done the command you wrote. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using mac os terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

The [CSV file specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2) is a bit too complex for handling csv files in a shell without additional tools (especially the quoting of fields that may contain the separator like `"field1","fie,ld2"`). I would rather recommend using perl or python:

```
python3 -c "import csv;print(len(next(csv.reader(open('$FILE')))))"
```

Comment: For this one, I can only use the shell unfortunately